# What is the expected input range for working with Keras VGG models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, vgg-net

I'm trying to use a pretrained VGG 16 from keras. But I'm really unsure about what the input range should be.

Quick answer, which of these color orders?

- RGB
- BGR

And which range?

- 0 to 255?
- balanced from about -125 to about +130?
- 0 to 1?
- -1 to 1?

I notice [the file where the model is defined](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py) imports an input preprocessor:

```
from .imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
```

But this preprocessor is never used in the rest of the file.

Also, when I check the [code for this preprocessor](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py/#L11), it has two modes: `caffe` and `tf` (tensorflow).

Each mode works differently.

Finally, I can't find consistent documentation on the internet.

So, what is the best range for working? To what range are the model weights trained?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The model weights were ported from caffe, so it's in [BGR format](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Image-Format:-BGR-not-RGB).

> Caffe uses a BGR color channel scheme for reading image files. This is
>   due to the underlying OpenCV implementation of imread. The assumption
>   of RGB is a common mistake.

You can find the original caffe model weight files [on VGG website](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/very_deep/). This link can also be found on Keras documentation.

I think the second range would be the closest one. There's no scaling during training, but the authors have subtracted the mean value of the ILSVRC2014 training set. As stated in [the original VGG paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf), section 2.1:

> The only preprocessing we do is subtracting the mean RGB value,
>   computed on the training set, from each pixel.

This sentence is actually what `imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(mode='caffe')` does.

1. Convert from RGB to BGR: because `keras.preprocessing.image.load_img()` loads images in RGB format, this conversion is required for VGG16 (and all models ported from caffe).
2. Subtract the mean BGR values: `(103.939, 116.779, 123.68)` is subtracted from the image array.

The preprocessor is not used in `vgg16.py`. It's imported in the file so that users can use the preprocess function by calling `keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(rgb_img_array)`, without caring about where model weights come from. The argument for `preprocess_input()` is always an image array in RGB format. If the model was trained with caffe, `preprocess_input()` will convert the array into BGR format.

Note that the function `preprocess_input()` is not intended to be called from `imagenet_utils` module. If you are using VGG16, call `keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input()` and the images will be converted to a suitable format and range that VGG16 was trained on. Similarly, if you are using Inception V3, call `keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input()` and the images will be converted to the range that Inception V3 was trained on.